# Can't call Celery in Django

Tags: python, django, django-celery

So the problem is that when I try to call *main* task from Django `lpr.views.py` page shows that loading icon and thats it, nothin else happens. There is no output in Django or Celery console. When I try and run the task from python shell it runs without a problem and saves result in db. I added *add* task for test purposes and when I run *add* task it returns an error because of missing 'y' argument which is normal. But what is up with that *main* task?

There is my code just in case.

Project structure:

```
Project
├── acpvs
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── lpr
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── manage.py
```

*settings.py*

```
import djcelery

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'djcelery',
    'django_celery_results',
]

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False

djcelery.setup_loader()
```

***init**.py*

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from acpvs.celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

*acpvs.celery.py*

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'acpvs.settings')

app = Celery('acpvs')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

*lpr.tasks.py*

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task
from djcelery import celery


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@shared_task
def main():
    ...
    args = {
        'imageName': imageName,
        'flag': True
    }

    return args
```

*lpr.urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^t/$', views.test_add),
    url(r'^t1/$', views.test_main),
]
```

*lpr.views.py*

```
from . import tasks
from django.http import HttpResponse



def test_add(request):
    result = tasks.add.delay()
    return HttpResponse(result.task_id)

der test_main(request):
    result = tasks.main.delay()
    return HttpResponse(result.task_id)
```

**Update**

It seems to me that there is still something wrong with that how I have integrated Celery. When I remowe `.delay()` from *views.py* it works but ofcourse not async and not using Celery.

Comment: Have you created a `__init__.py` file next to `celery.py`?

Comment: Yes, it's empty.

Comment: Your `__init__.py` file shouldn't be empty, Celery has a documentation on how to set it up with Django, refer to : http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html, you'll also have to give us more detail on your question, are you running workers, which version of celery are you using?

Comment: Yes, I know, I was folowing it, but for some reason have not set the `__init__.py`. I'll try that and post result.

Comment: I added `__init__.py` code but nothing changed. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Are you running workers on another console?

Comment: Yes, I run in a seperate console: `celery -A acpvs worker -l info`

Comment: Your add `x` and `y` and main `imageName` may be both are expecting parameters.

Comment: Yes `add` method is expecting parameters but `main` does not, and it runs without a problem from python shell @AnupYadav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working by removing all djcelery instances and upgrading Django from 1.11 to 2.0.3

By the way I'm using Celery 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

delay() is actually execute the task asynchronously, Please confirm if it updating the values in db,
I think it will update the value in db (if *main* method is doing) but will not return the value since client adds a message to the queue, the broker then delivers that message to a worker which then perform the operation of *main*

Comment: No, in my case `delay()` seems to be the spot where my previously mentioned problem accure. If I remove `delay()` and change _views.py_ like this:
`def test_celery(request):
    result = main()
    return HttpResponse(result.get("imageName"))`
It runs as suposed and returns response.